# add cookie with $ dollar (eq $Dir=1) and allow to duplicate cookies

Tags: c#, cookies, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to add a cookie for a certain URL to webrequest

```
  request.CookieContainer.Add(new Uri(loginURI), new Cookie("$Dir", "/root/"));
```

It's says there is an error in filename $Dir. Why?

Also I need to duplicate cookie twice $Dir and $Date but it allows to set only 1 time.  Is it possible to fix?

Comment: Please post the exact error, and clarify the second question.

Comment: I need to add $Dir cookie twice to the CookieContainer:

Error:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.CookieException' occurred in System.dll
Additional information: forbidden part "Name"="$Dir" of file cookie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the dollar sign cannot be the first character in a cookie name.

Taken from this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a18ka3h2.aspx) article:

> The following characters must not be used inside name: equal sign,
>   semicolon, comma, newline (\n), return (\r), tab (\t), and space
>   character. The dollar sign character ("$") cannot be the first
>   character.

Hope this helps.